# When I press back on my modal class, and click on a new item in my Flat List, the data remains the same from the first item I have pressed

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Parent component:
Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null,
      show: false,
      varFoodId: null,
    };
  }
```

This is the function where I fetch the data with an API request

```
fetchData = (item) => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?ingr=${item}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          itemArray: responseJson.hints,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
```

The button I press to fetch the data and return a Flat List with info regarding the individual items. Which are all touchable.

```
<Button
              title="Search"
              onPress={() => this.fetchData(this.state.item)}
            />
    <View style={styles.paddingForResultsContainer}>
              <FlatList
                style={styles.resultsBackground}
                data={this.state.itemArray}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.setState({
                        show: true,
                      })
                    }
              >
```

The modal component at the bottom of the parent component

```
              <NewModal
                  showUs={this.state.show}
                  toggleShow={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
                  foodInfo={item}
                ></NewModal>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
```

My child component for the modal:

```
const NewModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal  visible={props.showUs}/*visible={props.show} */>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <View>
  <Text>{props.foodInfo.food.nutrients.CHOCDF}</Text>
          <Button title="props" onPress={() => console.log({props})} />
          <Button title="Back" onPress={() => props.toggleShow()}></Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: You want to be running `fetchData` from the `onPress` within the `FlatList`'s `TouchableOpacity` right?

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately I am still getting the same result :/

Comment: fetchOnPressOpacity(){
          this.setState({
          show: true,
         })
            this.fetchData(this.state.item)
       };

Comment: Hmm ok so your issue isn't about fetching data, I think the issue is that you have `this.state.show` passed to ALL `NewModal` components, so if `this.state.show` is true, all modals are visible, and if it's false, none are visible.

Comment: I see, so what do you propose to fix this?

Comment: I'd say just render standard viewable components in the FlatList and when you click the item in the list, store `item` to the state, and `show` to `true` (as you're doing). Then you can have the NewModal rendering outside of the FlatList

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I found the issue, inside getData I created a new constant, in which I used the parseInt() method to turn the string from async data into an int, then setting the state to that constant I just made:

```
 getData = async () => {
    try {
      const totalCalories = await AsyncStorage.getItem("totalCalories");
      const x = parseInt(totalCalories);
      if (totalCalories !== null) {
        this.setState({
          totalCalories: x,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```